# Bash command to check if screen timed-out / screen locked / user is inactive

Tags: bash, scripts, lock-screen

I use crontab to run a script that takes a screenshot of my screen every 20 minutes, then adds it to a specific folder. However lots of times I leave my computer to do other things and the screen locks (screen turns black, and if I try to use the computer again I have to insert my password). I'd like to add an "if" in my script that doesn't take the screenshot if my screen is in this locked state. How can I do that?

Obs: I tried `gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep "is active"` and it seems to work when the screen it black, but not for when it shows the screen right after, asking for my password.

Comment: Idea: If you use `cmp` on two subsequent files, does it tell they're different? Limited amount of output compered to when the changes are "big" or not?

Comment: not sure what you mean, but i tried running `cmp index.js package.json` between two different files and the output was `index.js package.json differ: byte 1, line 1`, does this help?

Comment: If you have TEXT--files, then use `diff` (js := javascript, json := data, both might be text), I got the impression you had IMAGES, then `cmp` will possibly be a tool for you. Though; I do not know if the IMAGES will be "same" to the level that cmp can detect that. The basic idea is to skip saving the same image over and over again.